# CodeIgniter Login Authentification redirect based on usertype

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, authentication

I'm starting with CodeIgniter, and I must admit not very advanced in php. 
I need to redirect users to different pages based on the roles given to them in the database. Only the username and password is submitted on the login page. I have to fetch the role from the database which looks like this:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyZcU.png

Answer (score 0):

Usual login process goes like this:

(1) Validate form

(2) If validation successful, check given login credentials against the database

(3) If credentials are correct, redirect

In your case, you need to extend point 3, so:

(3) If credentials are correct, check user type based on the credentials given, and redirect respectively. In other words, you need to work with if - elseif - else. This way spacific user will be redirected to specific page.

Comment: yes but how it can be done Only the username and password is submitted on the login page !

Comment: Assuming your username is unique (e.g. a unique email address) you can use this username to check the type of the user who is logging in. Depending on your database structure, this can be done using the same query and result you use to check the credentials, or an additional query - just for fetching the user type. If it's still unclear, showing some code might be helpful.